# Redefine the spring framework version to correct a vulnerability in a final version of spring boot (example: 2.5.15)

Tags: spring-boot, security, upgrade

I want to redefine the version of the spring framework using the final version of spring boot 2.5.15 to take into account the last vulnerability corrected in version 5.3.32, knowing that the version of the spring framework used is version 5.3.17 in the spring boot version 2.5.15.

Given the context, is this a good practice, knowing that I can no longer update the spring boot version because it is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a good practice to upgrade libraries the hard way for security reasons.

Sometimes, you need to patch security flaws like this while you wait either for the library with the issue to patch it or for you and your team to be able to catch up with the earliest version without the issue.

We dealt with the infamous log4j bug found by Minecraft players by updating it manually. Just make sure your application works and it should be fine. To reduce the chances of introducing bugs in your code, consider picking the earlier version without the issue.

That being said, I see you wrote spring boot as the library carrying the issue. Do you mean [this library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot)? If so, 2.7.18 does not have this vulnerability and updating spring boot would be the best course of action if you can.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the Spring Boot library. Yes, I also agree with you that it would be better to upgrade to spring boot library version 2.7.18. But important adaptations must be taken into account in our application following certain implementation choices linked to the architecture.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you knew that there was a spring boot 2.x.x version without this issue. `the final version of spring boot 2.5.15` part in our question seemed to indicate to me that spring boot 2.x.x was not updated anymore. I figured it might save you some hassle.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification and your answers. I actually wanted to stay in version 2.5.x for the spring boot library initially. But I think I'll try to upgrade to 2.7.18 as soon as possible.